# how to get the NodeID into views-view-field--field-image.tpl.php to create an <a href> redirect

Tags: views

this is my code:

```
<div class="img-wrapper">
  <div class="content">

  <?php $nodeurl = url('articles/' . $node->nid); krumo($node->nid); ?>
  <a href="<?php echo $nodeurl ?>"

    <div class="img-container <?php print $imageClass; ?>">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

my code is not fetching a proper nodeID and when i krumo it (inspect passed elements) it brings back a null value. My code seems correct, can i get some help :)?

Comment: this worked for us, we loaded the NID and added inside an href tag.
<a href="<?php print $alias; ?>">**   
<?php $alias = drupal_get_path_alias('node/' . $row->nid); ?>
<a href="<?php print $alias; ?>" a>

Answer (score 0):

This is in a view correct? I believe you need to use `node_load($nid)` to load the node data first in order to fetch it. I would try something like this

```
$node = node_load($nid);
$nodeurl = url('articles/' . $node->nid);
```